# Assigning two values to one key in an object

Tags: javascript, blackjack

I am trying to create blackjack in JavaScript. I have the majority of the game done just trying to tackle the problem that an Ace can be 1 or 11.

What is the best way to solve this?

I have this object:

```
let rank = {
  'A': 1,
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3,
  '4': 4,
  '5': 5,
  '6': 6,
  '7': 7,
  '8': 8,
  '9': 9,
  '10': 10,
  'J': 10,
  'Q': 10,
  'K': 10
};
```

And this for my suits:

let suit = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades'];

Comment: That logic needs to be special cased when you resolve the rank.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: it would be interesting to see how you are calculating the values, please make a fiddle

Comment: By design. The difference  is that the total of a hand can have two values if it has at least one ace in it and one possible total is under 11 (nobody draws on 21). So the first question to ask is how are you going to handle hands with two values?  And you need to check for blackjack first. That needs to be resolved before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

You could have array(s) as values like:

```
let rank  = {
  'A': [1, 11],
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3,
  '4': 4,
  '5': 5,
  '6': 6,
  '7': 7,
  '8': 8,
  '9': 9,
  '10': 10,
  'J': 10,
  'Q': 10,
  'K': 10
};
```

or

```
let rank  = {
  'A': [1, 11],
  '2': [2],
  '3': [3],
  '4': [4],
  '5': [5],
  '6': [6],
  '7': [7],
  '8': [8],
  '9': [9],
  '10': [10],
  'J': [10],
  'Q': [10],
  'K': [10]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let rank = {
  'A': {
    yourKey  : 1,
    yourKey2 : 11
  },
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3,
  '4': 4,
  '5': 5,
  '6': 6,
  '7': 7,
  '8': 8,
  '9': 9,
  '10': 10,
  'J': 10,
  'Q': 10,
  'K': 10
};
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, you should add an explanation to it describing why/how the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. The value of an Ace is 1, period. Then when you evaluate the total of a hand, you apply these rules:

1. Total the value of each card.
2. If, and only if, the total is less than 12, AND there is at least one ace in the hand, add 10.

That's it. There is never any "choice" about it, and never more than one.  You also have to keep track of the fact that such a hand is "soft" because that affects the rules.

This should be done in the "hand evaluation" routine. There's no need to complicated the evaluation of each card--that's just how we describe it to humans because our brains don't work. Also, you really shouldn't be using strings to represent cards in the first place. Use numbers, and convert to strings only upon output to humans.

Comment: Ok first part makes sense. But I don't think I am using strings to represent cards. I am using the keys as strings and the values as numbers. Thus allowing me to do the simple calculations easily..

Comment: I haven't seen the whole code, but it looks to me like your card object is a rank and suit, which are strings, and you look up the value, rather than having the cards themselves just be numbers from which you calculate the value and look up the strings. I could be wrong, but it's typical of young programmers to overuse strings when they don't really apply.

Comment: I run this code:
   `Object.keys(rank).forEach(function(key) {
        for (var k=0; k < suit.length; k++){
          deck.push({ rankKey: key, rankValue: rank[key], suit: suit[k]})
        }
    });`
that gives me an array of objects with 3 Keys and so I do have strings but also numbers where appropriate I think :)

Comment: Yes, but you're doing hash lookups inside the loop to add up a hand. I suppose that's probably inevitable in JavaScript since it doesn't have real arrays, but in a more conventional language that would be expensive.

Answer (score -1):

You could assign `rank.A` to an array of values, but at some point you'll likely need to write a function that calculates which value to return based on the other cards the player is holding.

For example,

```
let rank  = {
  'A': [1, 11],
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3,
  '4': 4,
  '5': 5,
  '6': 6,
  '7': 7,
  '8': 8,
  '9': 9,
  '10': 10,
  'J': 10,
  'Q': 10,
  'K': 10
};

function calulateSum(hand) {
  let sum = 0;

  if (hand.some(v => v === rank.A)) { // if hand contains 'rank.A'
    // calculate value of 'A' based on total value
    // of the other cards in the hand
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: It'd be very helpful to know why this was downvoted…